# Loading GEOJSON in Leaflet and separating attributes

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm making a cloropleth map with geoJSON and Leaflet. Right now each year has a separate geoJSON file and I load each of them as below:

```
function loadGeoJSON(data) {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            global: false,
            url: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        return json;
    }


  var ccc2 = loadGeoJSON("t2015.geojson");
    var t2015 = L.geoJson(ccc2, {
        style: style,      
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature

    });
map.addLayer(t2015);

var ccc3 = loadGeoJSON("t2014.geojson");
    var t2014 = L.geoJson(ccc3, {
        style: style,      
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature

    });
```

The geoJSON are of countries and are the same each year. I would like to combine the geoJson files into one with each feature having the attributes: 2014_1, 2014_2, 2014_3, 2015_1, 2015_2, 2015_3 etc. Is it possible to load one file with all years and break it into variables which only has the attributes from a single year (i.e. 2014_1, 2014_2, 2014_3) so they can be separate layers on the map?

EDIT: SAMPLE COMBINED GEOJSON (note: geographies are not in full)

```
 
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FIPS_CNTRY": "AG", "CNTRY_NAME": "Algeria", "2013": 9698, "2013_2": 9545, "2014": 266, "2014_2": 52918, "2015": 91, "2015_2": 842 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ -5.152134895324707, 30.180469512939453 ], [ -5.139167308807373, 30.192359924316406 ], [ -5.080972671508789, 30.262359619140625 ], [ -5.048055648803711, 30.316665649414063 ], [ -5.029167175292969, 30.359165191650391 ], [ -5.010833740234375, 30.393886566162109 ]]}},
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FIPS_CNTRY": "AL", "CNTRY_NAME": "Albania", "2013": 7326, "2013_2": 1245, "2014": 834, "2014_2": 135, "2015": 785, "2015_2": 134 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates":  [ [ 20.791923522949219, 40.431541442871094 ], [ 20.787220001220703, 40.394721984863281 ], [ 20.758609771728516, 40.311943054199219 ], [ 20.73680305480957, 40.307220458984375 ], [ 20.714302062988281, 40.270099639892578 ], [ 20.721246719360352, 40.225135803222656 ]] }},
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FIPS_CNTRY": "AN", "CNTRY_NAME": "Andorra", "2013": 6698, "2013_2": 9578, "2014": 24266, "2014_2": 546, "2015": 425, "2015_2": 3145 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates":  [ [ 1.445833206176758, 42.601943969726563 ], [ 1.486527681350708, 42.650413513183594 ], [ 1.559722185134888, 42.655967712402344 ], [ 1.698333263397217, 42.626106262207031 ], [ 1.738610982894898, 42.616386413574219 ], [ 1.78171968460083, 42.569961547851563 ]]}},
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FIPS_CNTRY": "AU", "CNTRY_NAME": "Austria", "2013": 2592, "2013_2": 311, "2014": 66, "2014_2": 511, "2015": 242, "2015_2": 8664 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates":  [ [ 10.471235275268555, 46.871353149414063 ], [ 10.488205909729004, 46.935993194580078 ], [ 10.429998397827148, 46.984161376953125 ], [ 10.390763282775879, 47.002567291259766 ], [ 10.350624084472656, 46.991241455078125 ], [ 10.323331832885742, 46.955551147460938 ]] }},
]
}
```

Comment: can you post a sample of the json files you want to combine? Or a link to a couple of complete ones if they are public?

Comment: Once your GeoJSON data is merged in a single object with different property keys for each year, you would probably load it with `L.geoJson` several times (once per layer / year / quarter?) with a different `onEachFeature` function each time (so that it reads the appropriate property key).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Add a function that loops over the features in the geojson file and split them on the desired attribute values, returning several feature-collections.

And, please look into handling async ajax calls and deal with callbacks..

Comment: Just to add to this, be careful with Javascript as it is Asynchronous. See: http://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/

What will happen is that in your code you are returning values and assigning them to something that is used later. Note that code in Javascript isn't executed in sequence, but based on what finishes first... Just be aware!